# $(document).ready(function() { doesn't work after div was loaded

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a working while loading a `div`, `$(document).ready(function() {` works well before `div` load, but it stop working after `div` loaded. Why is it happening?

Here is the sample of code I am working with:

```
<div id="abc0">
    <div id="abc">    
        <script>
               $(document).ready(function() { 
                   alert("test");
               });   
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the load function I am using:

```
$("#abc0").load('mypage #abc');
```

Comment: Does it work if you put `alert("test");` outside the document ready?

Comment: It's working fine here...do you have any error in console?

Comment: simply remove the $(document).ready function from div and put simple alert.

Comment: Either I'm mistaken (because it's so early in the morning (for me :D)), or you are replacing the div with the script inside. The script cannot be executed if you remove/replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Use callback function for alert.

```
$("#abc0").load("mypage #abc > *", function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: That's different. He wants to load the Javascript dynamically with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
alert("test me");
});
```

Some time you have to write jQuery instead of $

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//do jQuery stuff when DOM is ready
});
```